# Developing a drawing utility in C#

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing

I am trying to create a simple drawing utility as .net desktop application(i.e Windows Form using C#). What i am planing to develop is:

1. There should be a canvas area (This is the area where the actual drawing is performed).
2. The canvas should be zoomable (Zoom in and zoom out)
3. The canvas areas should have grid lines (the ideal size of grid is 100X100pixel, but it can be changed with zooming)
4. There is a single character written inside each cell (here by the term "cell" i am refering to the box that is formed by the intersection of grid lines)

Now until this step all the thing are automatic (i.e user don't have to do anything until now all is done by my application)

1. User is only allowed to draw rectangles in canvas area(my application will also need to keep the track of those rectangles in such a way that user is allowed to resize those rectangles later)

Since i am beginner to C# so i need only guidance. Till now i just look at System.Drawing library (only look at it don't go deep :P) but not sure should it cater all my requirements or not (but i guess it will cater my req) and if it will then from where do i start with and what resource do i need to study in order to create this application.

Comment: What you need to do is: start creating and then, when you have a specific problem, post a question here.  You have the documentation for `System.Drawing` - what part are you struggling with?

Comment: As a beginner, My suggestion is to first you should implement your plans and try to go one by one with some approaches (Like ButtomUp approach). Here nobody will develop whole application for you so you need to ask a specific questions when you'll stuck.